# Bound variable not updating in function in Nativescript (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, android, listview, nativescript

### Context

I have a page where a `listview` can be toggled visible/hidden using a function called when tapping a button.

The `listview` element has the `visibility` attribute set to

```
{{ showFixtures ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}
```

When I initially bind the page, the `showFixtures` variable is set to `false` and the `listview` is hidden. When reversed, the `listview` is shown. This proves that the `showFixtures` variable is initially bound.

When the button is tapped, the `showFixtures` variable is supposed to be toggled between `true` and `false`. I can tap the button and call the function and see that the page variables have changed, however the `listview` element does not become visible/hidden (depending on context).

### Code

*`page.xml`*

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <!-- ... -->
<Label text="Toggle Fixtures" ontap="toggleFixtures"  />
    <ListView items="{{ fixturesList }}" visibility="{{ showFixtures ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
        <ListView.item>
            <GridLayout class="list-matches-ko" rows="30" columns="auto,*">
                <Label row="0" col="0" class="list-matches-ko-date" text="{{ koLabelDate }}" />
                <Label row="0" col="1" class="list-matches-ko-time" text="{{ koLabelTime }}" />
            </GridLayout>
        </ListView.item>
    </ListView>
    <!-- ... -->
</Page>
```

*`page.js`*

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var pageData = new observableModule.Observable;

exports.loaded = loaded;
function loaded(args){
    page = args.object;
    pageData.showFixtures = false;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
}

//...

exports.toggleFixtures = toggleFixtures;
function toggleFixtures(args){
    pageData.showFixtures = pageData.showFixtures ? false : true;
    console.log(args.object.bindingContext.showFixtures);
    console.log(page.bindingContext.showFixtures);
    console.log(pageData.showFixtures);
}
```

### Output

When the button is tapped three times, the output on the console is:

```
JS: true
JS: true
JS: true
JS: false
JS: false
JS: false
JS: true
JS: true
JS: true
```

### Question

How can I make the `listView` element visible/hidden with this function by using the bound variable, and why isn't it working the way it is now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the plain nativescript observable try something like the following

`pagedata.set('showFixtures', YOUR TERNARY HERE)`

Comment: Yes thank you this worked. Can you explain why this is the case? What do you mean by the "plain nativescript observable"?

Comment: You're using the core nativescript observable which isn't the same as what most consider an observable due to rxjs owning observables now. So it's the way the plain nativescript observable works. You could add a getter and setter for that prop and then update it in the manner you attempted initially. Without a getter setter the `set()` method is the approach for the observable instance. that could be explained further but should be simple enough to start making sense.

Comment: Here is the docs for the observable instance you are using. https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_data_ if you want to see more